# Number of Flops in Pseudocode

Tags: calculus, computer-science, computer-arithmetic

I have the following pseudocode:

[image]

And I want to find the number of flops (floating point operations) in the code. I need to write my final answer in terms of only $n$. Since every variable in each loop is different, I am quite confused on how to reach that point. I do see that the only flop in the code is the addition in the most inner loop. This is what I could come up with:

$\sum _{i=1}^n\:\left(\sum _{j=1}^i\:n-j-1\right)$

But, this does not look correct and I am not sure how I would write it in terms of only $n$.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of first $i$ numbers?

Comment: Yes. But I am not exactly sure how I would apply it here.

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^i n-j-1=\sum_{j=1}^i (n-1)-\sum_{j=1}^i j$ the second sum is exactly that.

Comment: Besides the other problems, don't forget to count the multiplication between $a_{ij}$ and $x_{ij}$ as a FLOP. The effect is simple, the number of FLOPS just doubled from what you previously counted.